# Emacs is it possible to get the action of C-x C- - (reduce buffer font size) in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to reduce the default font size for a buffer using Emacs lisp.

At the moment I am running a process based buffer as a small emacs-lisp based application, I want the font size to reduce in the same way as <kbd>C-x C--</kbd> does, when the app creates it's buffer.

The app has it's own major mode, so should I just set a custom basic face instead?

(note: I tried doing <kbd>C-x ESC ESC</kbd> but it showed the command executed before <kbd>C-x C--</kbd> instead.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to dmckee, Help does of course tell me the command that <kbd>C-x C--</kbd> executes...

The lisp to reduce is...

```
(text-scale-adjust -1)
```

to enlarge...

```
(text-scale-adjust 1)
```

to reset to default...

```
(text-scale-adjust 0)
```

Emacs also provides (which FYI `text-scale-adjust` wraps):

```
(text-scale-increase INC)  
;;INC is number of steps to increase

(text-scale-decrease DEC) 
;;DEC is number of steps to decrease
```

Answer (score 6):

In general <kbd>C-h k [key combination]</kbd> will tell you what a particular key combination is bound to. My emacs has <kbd>C-x C--</kbd>, undefined, but it is version 22.3.1. Perhaps you are using version 23.